Given a Serum or Vital preset, how can I find the closest sounding other presets? Or even better, rank the other presets by descending similarity?
I have many Serum and Vital presets. Given a Serum or Vital preset, how can I find the closest sounding other presets? Or even better, rank the other presets by descending similarity?

I think the primary issue with this goal is that sound similarity is not a well-defined, objective concept. You’d have to first prioritize for yourself which elements make two sounds most similar before you could compare the amounts of those elements in various presets.

@ToddWilcox thanks, true, could use sth akin to Ableton's Sound Similarity Search

I'm afraid the common method is still browsing presets and manual tagging for future use. For example in Vital, for each preset you can:

Select one of 9 styles
Give a name, which you can use to search sounds. E.g. "buzzy pluck" will be found when typing either "buzzy" or "pluck"
Star favorite preset

As mentioned in the comments, there are some tools for automatic categorizing samples. But a synthesizer presets it is often more complex than a single timbre. For example:

many presets have macro parameters set up to adjust parameters easily, changing the timbre. In particular, mod wheel often allows blending between very different timbres
polyphony
how consecutive notes are connected (e.g. settings of envelope, glide, legato)
some presets include distinct rhythmic elements that synchronize with tempo of the song, like LFOs, arpeggiators
most common presets have well defined pitch, but some are percussive, while some others play whole chords or intervals
effects
layering of different timbres

This is an open list, and the relevance of various of these factors vary a lot too.
I would hate to believe what you're asking is impossible, in fact I'm sure many people dream of such functionality - but it seems to me a difficult, and not well defined problem.
